# Google App Script Search with RegExp wild character

Tags: regex, google-apps-script, wildcard

I have a col that has text (var A1String)

1. Regenerist Anti Ageing Micro Sculpting Serum
2. Meghalaya Grass & Plastic   (Brown & Pink)
3. Meghalaya Grass & Plastic   (Brown & Pink)
4. Dentastix  Large Breed Treat (7 Pcs, Adult)
5. 5 Star Magic Pro-Health Chocolate  (Refill)

In a separate col I key in Search_Keys (var repstring) - eg

"Anti Ageing Serum"

"5 Star Chocolate"

I am trying to convert my keyed in entry to a regexp with wild characters to avoid "Micro Sculpting" in line 1, or "Magic Pro-Health" in line 5.

I tried the following code:

```
var split_repstring = repstring.split(' ');
var regex_repstring = new RegExp(split_repstring[0]+"\\?",'g');
for (var e=1;e<split_repstring.length;e++)
{regex_repstring=new RegExp(regex_repstring+split_repstring[e]+("\\?"),'g');}
```

and then search my table (A1String) as follows:

```
var a = A1String.search(regex_repstring);
```

The Logger output is:

```
[18-06-15 10:16:58:090 PDT] [Anti, Ageing, Serum]
[18-06-15 10:16:58:091 PDT] 3.0
[18-06-15 10:16:58:092 PDT] ///Anti\?/gAgeing\?/gSerum\?/g
```

And needless to say, the search is not returning the intended result.

Would someone be able to guide me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please provide a link to a sample spreadsheet? BTW, I created something like `=REGEXMATCH($A1:$A, ".*("&JOIN(".*", SPLIT(JOIN("|", $B$1:$B$2), " ")) &").*")` formula that takes 2 search terms in B1 and B2 and searches for matches in Column A. Do you want something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### tl;dr

You can build the regular expression I think you're looking for using just [String.prototype.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

```
new RegExp(repstring.replace(/ /g, ' .*'))
```

#### Example

I created a test table:

```
+-------------------------------------------------+-------------------+
| 1. Regenerist Anti Ageing Micro Sculpting Serum | Anti Ageing Serum |
| 2. Meghalaya Grass & Plastic   (Brown & Pink)   | 5 Star Chocolate  |
| 3.  Meghalaya Grass & Plastic   (Brown & Pink)  |                   |
| 4. Dentastix  Large Breed Treat (7 Pcs, Adult)  |                   |
| 5. 5 Star Magic Pro-Health Chocolate  (Refill)  |                   |
+-------------------------------------------------+-------------------+
```

Here's a script using the approach described above:

```
function search() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  var data = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 5).getValues()
  var queries = sheet.getRange(1, 2, 2).getValues();

  var queryRegexes = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < queries.length; i++) {
    queryRegexes[i] = new RegExp(queries[i][0].replace(/ /g, ' .*'));
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < queryRegexes.length; i++) {
    Logger.log('Results for ' + queryRegexes[0]);
    Logger.log(data.filter(function(entry) {
      return queryRegexes[i].test(entry);
    }));
  }
}
```

And here's the logging output:

```
[18-06-15 11:28:11:387 PDT] Results for /Anti .*Ageing .*Serum/
[18-06-15 11:28:11:388 PDT] [[1. Regenerist Anti Ageing Micro Sculpting Serum]]
[18-06-15 11:28:11:389 PDT] Results for /Anti .*Ageing .*Serum/
[18-06-15 11:28:11:389 PDT] [[5. 5 Star Magic Pro-Health Chocolate  (Refill)]]
```

Comment: new RegExp(repstring.replace(/ /g, ' .*')) is perfectly good. Worked well. Thank you